# Structuremap version 3, constructor Injection for IEnumerable<T> not working

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

I have some types like `ParentClassA` and `ParentClassB`, with their constructor having parameter as `IEumerable<IType>,` like shown in the code below.

```
    public interface IType
    { }
    public class TypeA : IType
    { }
    public class TypeB : IType
    { }
    public class ParentClassA
    {
        public ParentClassA(IEnumerable<IType> obj)
        {
            var d = obj;
        }
    }

    public class ParentClassB
    {
        public ParentClassB(IEnumerable<IType> obj)
        {
            var d = obj;
        }
    }
```

Now in Structuremap registry,(The version of Structuremap dll is 3.1.5.0) I want to setup the enumerables based on the context, means based on the parent object being created, something like,

```
For<IEnumerable<IType>>().Use(x => ff(x)).AlwaysUnique();

public IEnumerable<IType> ff(StructureMap.IContext x)
    {
        if (x.RootType.Name.Equals(typeof(ParentClassA).Name))
            return new List<IType>{ new TypeA() };
        else return new List<IType> { new TypeA() };
    }
```

but when I run the application(it builds fine), in the constructor of ParentClassA etc., I can only see an empty list being passed, but what I am expecting is the return list from function `ff`.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try calling `.ToList()` on var d?

Comment: its an empty array that is being injected in the constructor.

Comment: I've encountered the same behavior, I'm not sure how to resolve the issue.